# Require Select Not Allow First Option

Tags: javascript, html

Say we have the following:

```
<select name="select" required>
<option disabled selected value>Please Select Option</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

I would like this field to be required but I do not want to allow the user to submit the first option (`<option disabled selected value>Please Select Option</option>`)

By default, the first option (`<option disabled selected value>Please Select Option</option>`) should be selected until the user changes the option.

I've tried doing Googling this problem but I'm only able to find different problems but not this particular one. My thoughts is that it would have to use Javascript to accomplish this but I  would like to use an HTML option before going that route.

Thank you for help!

Comment: You may want to use validation in here. In Jquery http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Have my answer is working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using JS**

```js
$("#clickButton").click(function (event) {
    var picked = $('#selector option:selected').val();
    if (picked == 0) {
        alert("Please select any value");
    } else {
        console.log("Selected")
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector" name="select" required>
    <option disabled selected value="0">Select</option>
    <option>Data 1</option>
    <option>Data 2</option>
    <option>Data 3</option>
</select>

<button id="clickButton" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<select>
    <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Select language</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Much more complicated than the awesome witchcraft @Mr. HK showed, but another approach:

HTML:

```
<select id="selector" name="select" required>
<option disabled selected value="0">Please Select Option</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<button id="mainButton" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#mainButton").click(function(event) {
var picked = $('#selector option:selected').val();
if (picked == 0){
alert("you must pick an option")
}
else{
//do whatever
}
})
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ShL4T/105/

Answer (score 1):

if you do not mind using php or javascript to validate the input of the select. tag.
here is a simple javascript verification:

```js
    function verify(){
      var somevar = document.getElementById("select").value;
        if(somevar == 'Please Select Option'){
         document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = 'Invalid Choice, Please choose Option 1, 2, or 3';
    }else{
        //do whatever you want to do
    }
    }
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
    <select name="select" id="select" required>
    <option disabled selected>Please Select Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    </select>
    
    <button type="submit" onclick="verify()" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: im sorry about the first answer i kinda messed it up im a little rusty in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form>
  <select name="select" required>
    <option disabled selected value>Please Select Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select id="option" name="select" required>
    <option disabled selected value="0">Please Select Option</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
     </select>
```